# Draw a hexagon with fill and thick outline

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am generating a hexagon via this code obtained from [Harvey Sheppard](https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX):

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\hexagon}{O{Black} m m O{}}{
    \fill [#1, #4] ($ (#2) + (0:#3) $) -- ($ (#2) + (60:#3) $) -- ($ (#2) + (120:#3) $) -- ($ (#2) + (180:#3) $) -- ($ (#2) + (240:#3) $) -- ($ (#2) + (300:#3) $) -- cycle;
}
```

How to add a thick red outline to this hexagon?

Comment: Please don't post snippets.  Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: The command would probably be more flexible if it used `\draw` with a `fill` option...

Comment: @Thruston, can you post an example of your suggestion?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the context how you plan to use this, but here is a command `\myhex` that takes two arguments, one optional.

`\myhex[<redthickness>]{<radius>}`

Default `redthickness` is 1.5mm.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myhex}[2][1.5mm]{\draw[red, line width=#1,fill=black](0:#2)--(60:#2)--(120:#2)--(180:#2)--(240:#2)--(300:#2)--cycle;}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\myhex{1cm}\begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]\myhex[2mm]{8mm}\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using `shapes.geometric` from `tikz` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[regular polygon, 
    draw, 
    regular polygon sides = 6, 
    minimum size = 2in,
    fill=black, 
    draw=red,
    line width=6pt,
    ] (p) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can compile your document with `lualatex`, then you could also use this [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) alternative. The `luamplib` package lets you include MP code as part of your macro definitions, with direct access to the usual macro parameters.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\newcommand{\rhex}[2][0.5]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\begin{mplibcode}beginfig(0);
path p; p = for i=0 upto 5: (#2, 0) rotated 60i -- endfor cycle;
fill p withcolor 3/4[red, white]; 
draw p withpen pencircle scaled #1 withcolor 2/3 red;
endfig;\end{mplibcode}}}}
\begin{document}
In normal text: \rhex{5pt}.
Inside maths mode: $\rhex[1]{5pt} + \left(\rhex7\right)^2$
\end{document}
```

Here I have defined a command that will work in text mode or math mode.  If you compile this with `lualatex` you should get something like this:

[image]